# CSS Card flip creating unwanted response when rotating back

Tags: css

This is for a simple card flip. The front face has 'FIRST' written onto it. 
When I hover my over the div, the card flips to back face and when the mouse leaves, the card flips back to front face.

At the point, when the mouse is about to leave, immediately, the card shows the front face inverted, and then it rotates back to normal orientation. I believe it is skipping the 0.6s transition when it is about to rotate back.

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0e28d81/)

Thoughts?
CSS:

```
    h1{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    .container{
        margin: auto;
        left: 34%;
        top: 20%;
        position: relative;
      }
    .card{
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 300px;
      }
     .card:hover{
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
      }
     .front{
        border: 2px solid;
        border-radius: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       }
     .back{
        border: 2px solid;
        border-radius: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        background: blue;
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;    
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       }
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='card'>
        <div class='front'>
            <h1>First</h1>
        </div>
       <div class='back'>
            <h1>Last</h1>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change backface-visibility to visible
and move the transform-style: preserve-3d;to the .card class
if there is one place to use this style, it's here.
here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0e28d81/4/)

```
  .card{
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
```

Comment: Nothing changed by adding backface-visibility to .card class

Comment: you problem is the inverted first writing?

Comment: Yes. As soon as the is about to flip back, instead of the backface slowly rotating to reveal the frontface, the frontface immediately shows up inverted and then turns back to normal orientation.

Comment: check out the JSFiddle link I have made some changes, check if what you want

Answer (score 0):

The backface of an element is a transparent background always, backface property already mentioned in `.front` and `.back` class. Not really needed in `.card` css.

> Removed backface from card class.

```
.card{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/ruhofereza/2/

Comment: Tried doing that, didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please set your 3d perspective view for card flip. Please add this code inside  the container div.

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

like this

```
 .container{
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

Comment: That did change outlook of the animation a bit, but the error with the inverted "first" writing is still happening